# How can I use REGEX in a meta query.

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have a string submitted from a form field to my query, for example:

1159

The meta value is CFN-1159 but I want to be able to run the query without always using the full meta value.

My array is as follows:

```
//The submitted reference code
$ref = $_POST['ref'];  

//The array added to the meta query
$ref_query = array(        
   'meta_key' => 'reference_code',
   'meta_value' => array($ref),
   'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'        
);
```

Im looking to only return the post with the unique ref code (meta_value).

How could I use REGEX instead of LIKE here to find posts where the meta value "ends with" the submitted string.

Comment: Please try my answer below

Comment: what's the $_POST['ref] return

Comment: Any value put into it. If i post 1159 then I only want to return the post with the meta value CN-1159.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use something like that

```
 $query_adresses = array (
'order'     => 'ASC',
'post_type'=> 'your_post_type',
'posts_per_page'   => '-1',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'reference_code',
        'value'   => array($_POST['ref']),
        'compare' => 'REGEXP'
    )
)
```

);

Comment: Whilst this did return the post with the value, it was nested amongst all the others. So this didnt work. 
Also, where is the expression in your solution?